# Get full google contacts list using OAuth

Tags: android, oauth

I'm trying to receive the user contact list from gmail using this (http://androidwarzone.blogspot.com.br/2011/07/android-oauth-full-example-with-source.html) tutorial. Everything worked just great, but I'm just receiving 24 contacts, nothing more, nothing less. If i delete an contact that is receiving and try to get the list again, ir brings me another contact placing the deleted spot.

How do I get the full list? There is a better way instead of this tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

All contacts, including gmail, can be queried directly from the contacts content provider on the device.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html#Access

Comment: it will just work assuming that user had synchronized the contacts from account. I have to be sure about receive contact list.

Comment: Contact synchronization is a user's decision and, IMO, apps should respect that decision and user's privacy.

Comment: That is the case. I want to get user email list respecting the user decision about not have to synchronize it. Like me, I don't want to have all my contact email list in my phone, but I want some app to access this list.

Answer (score 0):

In the tutorial what u have mentioned, in C.java file, for GET_CONTACTS_FROM_GOOGLE_REQUEST use this url https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?max-results=1000&alt=json

Here max-results=1000 means maximum 1000 results to retrieve per request

Comment: Hi Prabhu above URL return all contacts i.e. contact from a contact list, sent mail and received mail but I want contact from only contact list not from sent and received mail.